# Angular cli - ng new stuck in Stylus

Tags: angular, angular-cli

my problem is trickly. I have successfully installed Nodejs and angular-CLI on ubuntu(VMware). However, no matter how I try to ng-new, the cmd will stuck like that and do nothing.
[image: error occur]

Here is my version information:
[image: enter image description here][2]

I have tried to play with angular in China, I don't know whether there is an issue on the Internet.
I have tried to clear the cache and reinstall, but it does not make any difference here. I have also tried to use a mirror image managed by Alibaba, which also does not change anything. I hope that there is someone who comes to help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: well it take some time to create a new angular project, how much time did you wait for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first screen shows you a **list of possible CSS preprocessors**. And Angular CLI **asks you** which one you would like to use. Just **navigate by "up"/"down" buttons** and click Enter.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe that I have stuck here. :)